# How do i get the x and y coordinates of the cropped image that is under a mask in my activity view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-camera2

I have a camera activity with a custom user interface. I have a masked filter, in which the user must focus on the desired image. After the image has been captured, I need to get the exact x and y coordinates of the image where the masking appears to crop it correctly. How can I do it.

Below are the images to show what I mean.

[Here is the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlPCI.jpg)

As you can see, the filter area, where masking is performed, I just want that part of the image to be cropped and shown in the view as below.
[Here is the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orVyh.jpg)

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the layout?

Comment: Sure. Will do that